# Cross validation with multiple parameters using f1-score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to do feature selection using SelectKBest and the best tree depth for binary classification using f1-score. I have created a scorer function to select the best features and to evaluate the grid search. An error of "**call**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'" pops up when the classifier is trying to fit to the training data.

```
#Define scorer
f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)
#Split data into training, CV and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 0)

#initialize tree and Select K-best features for classifier   
kbest = SelectKBest(score_func=f1_scorer, k=all)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

#create a pipeline for features to be optimized
pipeline = Pipeline([('kbest',kbest),('dt',clf)])

#initialize a grid search with features to be optimized
gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline,{'kbest__k': range(2,11), 'dt__max_depth':range(3,7)}, refit=True, cv=5, scoring = f1_scorer)

gs.fit(X_train,y_train)

#order best selected features into a single variable
selector = SelectKBest(score_func=f1_scorer, k=gs.best_params_['kbest__k'])
X_new = selector.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)  

On the fit line I get a TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y_true'.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `score_func` which you have used for `SelectKBest`. `score_func` is a  function which takes two arrays **X** and **y**, and returning a pair of arrays (scores, pvalues) or a single array with scores, but in your code you have fed the callable `f1_scorer` as the `score_func` which just takes your `y_true` and `y_pred` and computes the `f1 score`. You can use one of `chi2`, `f_classif` or  `mutual_info_classif` as your `score_func` for the classification task. Also, there is a minor bug in the parameter `k` for `SelectKBest` it should have been `"all"` instead of `all`. I have modified your code incorporating these changes,

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif  
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score, make_scorer
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_classes=2,
                       n_informative=4, weights=[0.7, 0.3],
                       random_state=0)

f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)
#Split data into training, CV and test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.25, random_state = 0)

#initialize tree and Select K-best features for classifier   
kbest = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

#create a pipeline for features to be optimized
pipeline = Pipeline([('kbest',kbest),('dt',clf)])
gs = GridSearchCV(pipeline,{'kbest__k': range(2,11), 'dt__max_depth':range(3,7)}, refit=True, cv=5, scoring = f1_scorer)
gs.fit(X_train,y_train)
gs.best_params_
```

**OUTPUT**

> {'dt__max_depth': 6, 'kbest__k': 9}

Also modify your last two lines as below:

```
selector = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=gs.best_params_['kbest__k'])
X_new = selector.fit_transform(X_train,y_train)
```

Comment: Hello Parthasarathy, thank you for this. Is there any way I can use the f1-score as the score function to select the best K features? I tried using f_classif, and the performance is worse than if I consider the entire feature set.

Comment: In the code above when you say `scoring = f1_scorer` you are using `f1_score` to evaluate how good the best `k` returned by the `SelectKBest` is. But for selecting the k best features you can't use `f1-score` which is basically a measure to evaluate  how good your model is performing. You need something like  `chi2`, `f_classif` or `mutual_info_classif` for doing this. I have also fixed the code a little bit.

Comment: Hi ABB, If you think this answer helped you resolve your problem, I kindly request you to accept it an answer, as it will help others to find the right answer if they also face similar issues. Thanks in advance! For more details please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers